# Php file not retrieving data from file directly

Tags: php, html, file-io, input

I have a folder of images and I only want to select specific images from that folder, so I created a .txt file with the names of the files i wanted to be selected from that folder, I then made it so that the .php file goes through that file and assigns each line to string, I then made it so that that string was the title of the filein the image source. For some reason it isnt working

here is my code:

```
$file = fopen("bremners.txt", "r");
 $members = array();

 while (!feof($file)) {
 $members[] = fgets($file);
 }

 fclose($file);
```

above is what reads in the file

below is how im trying to add the image

```
echo '<img src = "'.$members[3].'  height="200" width="150"; "
```

when I refesh the page the image doesnt appear

but if I just change the $members[3] to the name of the picture/file then it does work.

If someone could figure this out that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: If memory serves, fgets returns the newlines.  Try $members[] = trim(fgets($file))

Comment: @Jeremy Miller didnt fix it

Comment: In the code block echo '<img sr...' is that truncated, or is the >(caret) missing? Should it be width="150">'; on the end there?

Comment: yea, I have that, I just modified the code when I posted it here and messed it up, in my code i have that

Comment: Try $i=0; while($line = fgets($file)) { $members[$i] = $line; $i++; }

Comment: Try 
$members=array();
$file=fopen('bremners.txt', 'r');
while (!feof($file))
{
    $line=fgets($file);
    $line=trim($line);
    $members[]=$line;
}
fclose($file);